# Large performance hit with Python logging module

Tags: python, logging, python-logging

I typically use Python's inbuilt `logging` module to better debug my code during development. My typical codes are a bit performance sensitive. My assumption was that once I have completed debugging the code, I can simply set the logging level to `WARNING` and compiler would remove all the `logger` commands.

I decided to profile the code to be sure, and viola, when I commented out all the logging calls - my code performance was 20x better compared to the code that had logging turned off by setting higher level. Which means, when you increase the logging level, compiler still leaves the logging with a branch, and the CPU performance poorly due to all the branches!

Is this observation correct, or am I missing something completely?

Comment: It is a feature of `logging` module. Setting higher log level leaves some chained attribute accesses which are very time consuming in Python. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54470102/why-standard-logging-module-is-so-slow-when-disabled